# How to get all the custom fields values from dynamics crm 11?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

i'm using OrganizationServiceProxy to get all the fields values from the CRM server.But its returning only used fields values.It doesnt have unused custom field values. :( . how to get all the custom  fields values from crm2011.?

```
  using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(cons.createProxy(logfilePath)))
  {
     var contactlist =(from a in svcContext.ContactSet
     where a.new_proid.Equals(contact_id)
     select a);
  }
```

"new_proid" is custom fields.Its not available but all the other defaults values is available.

Comment: please share your actual code

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are using Early Bound, this means you generated the helper classes using `crmsvcutil.exe` from the SDK.

If you don't see some fields inside the `Contact` class it's because the field was created after the classes were generated.

You need to generate again the helper classes and include the new version inside your project.

Comment: In settings, I found the newly added custom fields values state is mentioned as "Unmanaged". Will it affect the process?

Comment: no, it will not affect the generation of the classes

Comment: The reason why i asked is, only managed values is available and all "unmanaged states" are not available..

Comment: check if you published the changes of your solution